# "Set Application.Workbooks.Open" return wrong value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue whit a code part, 
I'm trying to open 2 different workbooks and to assign the to different workbook variable ("*WBSOURCE*" and "*WBCIBLE*").

Fist I'm selecting my workbooks file path and I assign it on ("*sourcefile*" and "*ciblefile*"), and then I'm using "Set *WBCIBLE* = Application.Workbooks.Open(*ciblefile*)" and "Set *WBSOURCE*= Application.Workbooks.Open(*sourcefile*)" in order to open and save them as variable.

But for an unknow reason *WBSOURCE* and *WBCIBLE* a returning the same value (I selected different file for *sourcefile* and *ciblefile*)

Does anyone have an idea about what's wrong in this code ?

Many thanks in advance:

bellow the code

```
Public sourcefile As String
Public ciblefile As String


------------
Private Sub BoutonChoixCible_Click()
ciblefile = Application.GetOpenFilename 'ciblefile = au choix
Textbox_Cible.Value = ciblefile 'afficher le choix
End Sub

------------
Private Sub BoutonChoixSource_Click()

sourcefile = Application.GetOpenFilename 'sourcefile = au choix
Textbox_Source.Value = sourcefile 'afficher le choix
End Sub

------------
Private Sub BoutonMAJ_Click()

Dim WBSOURCE As Workbook 'ancienne balance
Dim WBCIBLE As Workbook 'nouvelle balance


Set WBCIBLE = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourcefile)
Call MsgBox(sourcefile)
Call MsgBox(WBSOURCE)
Set WBCIBLE = Application.Workbooks.Open(ciblefile)
Call MsgBox(ciblefile)
Call MsgBox(WBCIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're always setting `WBCIBLE`

so that would be:

```
Set WBSOURCE = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourcefile)
MsgBox sourcefile
MsgBox WBSOURCE.Name

Set WBCIBLE = Application.Workbooks.Open(ciblefile)
MsgBox ciblefile
MsgBox WBCIBLE .Name
```

but you'd better drop `Public` variables off and go with `TextBox` values directly

```
Private Sub BoutonMAJ_Click()

    Dim WBSOURCE As Workbook 'ancienne balance
    Dim WBCIBLE As Workbook 'nouvelle balance


    Set WBSOURCE = Application.Workbooks.Open(Textbox_Source.Value)
    MsgBox WBSOURCE .Name

    Set WBCIBLE = Application.Workbooks.Open(Textbox_Cible.Value)
    MsgBox WBCIBLE.Name

End Sub
```